# How to stop running instance of Floodlight?

Tags: java, multithreading, controls, osgi, bundle

I have created a OSGi bundle from mavenized floodlight. I use blueprint config.xml to activate the bundle. Here is the blueprint config.xml:

```
<bean id="flbean"
    class="net.floodlightcontroller.core.FloodlightBean"
    init-method="init" destroy-method="destroy">
</bean>
```

I create a class FloodlightBean which provides init() and stop() methods to start and stop the bundle:

```
public class FloodlightBean {

public void init() throws FloodlightModuleException {
    System.out.println("start floodlight");
    // Setup logger
    System.setProperty("org.restlet.engine.loggerFacadeClass",
            "org.restlet.ext.slf4j.Slf4jLoggerFacade");

    CmdLineSettings settings = new CmdLineSettings();
    /*CmdLineParser parser = new CmdLineParser(settings);
    try {
        parser.parseArgument(args);
    } catch (CmdLineException e) {
        parser.printUsage(System.out);
        System.exit(1);
    }*/

    // Load modules
    FloodlightModuleLoader fml = new FloodlightModuleLoader();
    IFloodlightModuleContext moduleContext = fml
            .loadModulesFromConfig(settings.getModuleFile());
    // Run REST server
    IRestApiService restApi = moduleContext
            .getServiceImpl(IRestApiService.class);
    restApi.run();
    // Run the main floodlight module
    IFloodlightProviderService controller = moduleContext
            .getServiceImpl(IFloodlightProviderService.class);
    // This call blocks, it has to be the last line in the main
    controller.run();
}

public void destroy() {

    System.out.println("stop floodlight");
}
```

}

For the init() method, I just copy the codes from net.floodlightcontroller.core.Main into it. Now floodlight can be started in the OSGi container. But the problem is that once floodlight bundle get started, it runs forever. I dont know how to implement destroy() to stop floodlight.

I just find out that floodlight is multithreaded. So I cant just simply create a thread for the codes inside net.floodlightcontroller.core.Main. 
I am wondering if I could create a process for init(), and implement killing that process in destroy(). 
Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

If the IFloodlightModuleLoader or Context has no stop/deactivate/close method that stops those threads you're officially screwed. Unofficially you could create a ThreadGroup before you call run. If you're lucky you can call setDaemon(true), this might help to kill the threads if they're the only ones using the VM. Otherwise you can call stop() on the ThreadGroup. This will likely work but is deprecated because it is unsafe.